# Replace Border Color without Effecting the weight of the Border

Tags: vba, excel

I am not much of a coder but I was trying to replace the border color without effecting the weight of the border in Excel but unfortunately the code I write doesn't. Request you guys to help me out with the fault in my code.

```
Sub BorderReplace()
Dim Top, Bottom, Left, Right
Cells.Select

'Save Border Weights
Top = Selection.Borders(x1EdgeTop).Weight
Bottom = Selection.Borders(x1EdgeBottom).Weight
Left = Selection.Borders(x1EdgeLeft).Weight
Right = Selection.Borders(x1EdgeRight).Weight

'Select Border Color
Selection.Borders.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)

'Reapply Border Weights
Selection.Borders(x1EdgeTop).Weight = Top
Selection.Borders(x1EdgeBottom).Weight = Bottom
Selection.Borders(x1EdgeLeft).Weight = Left
Selection.Borders(x1EdgeRight).Weight = Right

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance! Also a better code or a solution to the existing code is much appreciated. Although when i try to run the code, the following error Run time error : 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to get the border weights and reapply them. This below line is just enough to change the border color. Other properties will not get affected.

`Selection.Cells.Borders.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)`

Also, you are setting the `Borders` to `Selection`. This is not a valid action. You can set the `borders` to `Cells`. So, change `Selection.Borders` to `Selection.Cells.Borders`

**EDIT:**

Since you have multiple border styles, thick and thin in your selection, the default border style is applied.

```
Sub BorderReplace()
Dim Top, Bottom, Left, Right
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection

For Each cel In rng.Cells
    With cel
        Top = .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight
        Bottom = .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight
        Left = .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight
        Right = .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight

        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = Top
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = Bottom
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = Left
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = Right
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It applies the color successfully but ends with applying thin border to all the cells and does not retains the original border weights!

Comment: @AnkushSurana, No, it does not. The `Border.Weight` remains the same. please see the attached screenshot in the answer. Also, please share your edited code, so I can have a look.

Comment: Also out of curiosity, why isnt the code working anyway?

Comment: Here you go - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BTUMQ3qb6Y2p1R1diagnyJZp9SbxeGVn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey man! You are the best. But i still have a query, I just wanna replace the cells that do have borders in 'em with another color. But this code requires me to actually select those cells that i wanna replace.

Comment: You can just loop through the cells in the `UsedRange`. Change `Set rng = Selection` to `Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange`.

Comment: OMG! You have finally did it. Thanks mate. I know i took alot of your time. But you are the best. You solve problems like a grand master!